# Add the number 0 in front of a vector a number of times to obtain a vector of desired length

Tags: r

I have a vector with 349 data points

```
x<-(c(1:349))
```

I would like to add the number 0 in front of the vector a number of times equal to the difference of the vector lenght without 0s and 512. (to obtain a final vector of 512 data points)

Thank you

Bernabe

Comment: Just hoping this isn't to "fill in" a vector prior to performing an FFT :-).

Comment: Note that 1:349 already gives a vector so you don't need to wrap it in c() and wrapping that in () doesn't add anything either. `x <- 1:349` would do the same thing

Comment: Carl, you are almost right. I need to perform a DWT and would like to extract scaling and mother coeficients for all the series not just ^2 range. Any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> c(rep(0, 512-length(x)), x)
  [1]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [19]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
...
[145]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
[163]   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
...
[487] 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341
[505] 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349
```

Comment: Similar: `c(integer(512 - length(x)), x)`

Answer (score 1):

Less idiomatic option :)

```
y <- vector(mode='numeric',length=512)
y[seq_along(x)] <- rev(x)
rev(y)
```